# Bitwise operations on .ix (Pandas)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Why didn't the developers allow bitwise operations on .ix? Curious whether it is a matter of technical constraint or a logical issue I'm overlooking.

```
df.ix[df["ptdelta"]<=0 & df["ptdelta"]>5]
```

The traceback is:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'
```

'''

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Comment: Try surrounding your argument with parentheses. `df.ix[(df["ptdelta"]<=0) & (df["ptdelta"]>5)]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what's going on inside the square brackets-- `.ix` has nothing to do with it.  If you parenthesize appropriately, this works:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [-1,2,-3,4,6,-8.2]})
>>> df.ix[(df['a'] <= 0) | (df['a'] > 5)]
     a
0 -1.0
2 -3.0
4  6.0
5 -8.2
```

Otherwise you're trying to perform a bitwise op on (presumably) a float.  If it were an int, for example, then it'd "work":

```
>>> df['a'] <= 0 & df['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-40-9173361ec31b>", line 1, in <module>
    df['a'] <= 0 & df['a']
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'

>>> df['a'] <= 0 & df['a'].astype(int)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: a, Dtype: bool
```